# Moving Kinect Tilebutton between different grids

Tags: c#, kinect, interaction

I want to realize a table containing different Kinecttilebuttons. The buttons have to be able to be moved between different columns and rows. To realize the table I used a datagrid. Unfortunately once a button was sticked in a cell, it wasn't possible to change the cell the button was connected to. Is there any way how I can I create an application with the two requirements from above (table and movable kinecttilebutton)?

I'm very thankful for any advices, ideas or jump off points. Different approaches, like using other elements to create a table-like layout are welcomed too.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How would you like to move this button? do you mean smth like Drag&Drop using hand gestures?

Comment: I'm already moving the button with the mouse, but drag and drop is also okay